# getting int variable value from another servlet

Tags: servlets

I have a question regarding calling an int number from another servlet. Lets say I have 2 servlets. Servlet 1 gives me a variable number from a database. Im my servlet 2 I would like to have a function that can print out this variable. How can I do that?

The servlets interact with that I get a return value from the database called allay_hours_sum. That is a number, fx 35.5. In servlet 2 I would like to have a function where I can call this number. I have not made servlet 2 yet.

This is the code where I retrieve a number from the MySQL database:

```
String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "; //WHERE startDate='?' AND endDate='?' 
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

            float Allday_hours_sum = 0;
                while (rs.next()){                                      
                    Allday_hours_sum += rs.getFloat("Allday_hours"); 

                }   
                res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          
                res.getWriter().print(Allday_hours_sum);
```

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: How does servlet 1 and 2 interact with each other?

Comment: relevant question :-) I have audited my question. Hope you have an idea how to do it? I am planning to make a servlet that have a lot of functions, because I needs this number to make a lot of calculations

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable value in request

```
request.setAttribute("allay_hours_sum",allay_hours_sum);
```

pass the request to another servlet using RequestDispatcher

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("yourSecondServlet");
     rd.forward(request,response);
```

Then you can get the value in your second servlet

```
Integer allay_hours_sum=(Integer)request.getAttribute("allay_hours_sum");
```